# Can i make beacon plugin scan also normal bluetooth devices?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, beacon

I have a Flutter app that have implementation of [beacons_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/beacons_plugin). I can scan for beacons. But I am told to scan beacons and normal bluetooth devices too. Is there a way to do this? I think if I change the ranging code I will be able to do this but don't know if it's true. Even if it's true I don't know how to change it:

```
await BeaconsPlugin.addRegion(
        "BeaconType1", "909c3cf9-fc5c-4841-b695-380958a51a5a");
    await BeaconsPlugin.addRegion(
        "BeaconType2", "6a84c716-0f2a-1ce9-f210-6a63bd873dd9");
    await BeaconsPlugin.addRegion(
        "Aruba", "4152554e-f99b-4a3b-86d0-947070693a78");
```

Comment: Are planning on scanning devices advertising as Bluetooth Low Energy devices or do you want to scan Bluetooth Classic devices?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan classical or le, I want to scan every bluetooth device